# Validate against enum members in Python

Tags: python, enums

In Python, I have an input (called input_var below) that I would like to validate against a enum (called Color below). Is the following way the recommended Pythonic approach?

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    blue = 2
input_var = 'red'
if input_var in Color.__members__:
    print('Everything is fine and dandy.')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the built-in [`hasattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) function. `hasattr(object, name)` returns `True` if the `string` `name` is an attribute of `object`, else it returns `False`.

**Demo**

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    red = 1
    blue = 2

input_var = 'red'

if hasattr(Color, input_var):
    print('Everything is fine and dandy.')
```

**Output**

```
Everything is fine and dandy.
```