# Validate against enum values in Python

Tags: python, enums

**How can I validate a parameter passed by a user by ensuring it is one of the *values* of the members of an integer enum that already exists in my codebase?**

I have the following `SamplingRateEnum`:

```py
from enum import IntEnum, StrEnum

class SamplingRateEnum(IntEnum):
    SR_22050 = 22_050
    SR_44100 = 44_100
    SR_80000 = 88_000  # NOTE *not* 88_200
```

I could validate the user input as follows, getting the desired result in `valid_flag`, but this seems like a bad way to achieve this outcome:

```py
user_input = 22_050 
valid_flag = user_input in SamplingRateEnum.__members__.values()
```

In the related [Validate against enum members in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35084518/6619692), data had to be validated based on members' keys, and not their values. I want to validate data based on the latter.

Is there a better idiom or tool for this in the Python standard library? (I would like to avoiding an additional dependency just for this purpose.)

Comment: If you use `SamplingRateEnum(user_input)` it will raise a `ValueError` if it's not one of the valid values. Otherwise the resulting value can be used as if it was an integer.

Comment: what is the problem with your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `__members__.values()` with `iter`

```
valid_flag = user_input in iter(SamplingRateEnum)
```